# Loading View while ListView Is Fulling

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was trying to make a code that while filling a ListView there is a Loading View.

An example?

Thank you very much

Comment: ListFragment source...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'Loading View'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what I wanted when I am creating my music player app. Here is how I showed another screen while loading list view using AsyncTask (*runs in background*).

1) Create an activity (launcher) - LoadActivity.
2) Load list view contents using an AsyncTask while showing LoadActivity.
3) Open your MainActivity after loading is complete and close LoadActivity.

In an **AsyncTask**,
onPreExecute - Before background task.
doInBackground - background task.
onPostExecute - After background task.

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         // Before your task
     }

     protected Long doInBackground(Params... params) {
         // Your Task
         return result;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
         // After your task
         startActivity(new Intent(LoadActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
         finish();
     }
}
```

Then, in your onCreate() of LoadActivity.java,

```
new MyTask().execute(Params... params);
```

For more on AsyncTask, refer the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, that address was what I needed :)

Comment: @Jonatan Jourdan Your welcome.